# checking if a device has connection to the inernet doesn't work android code

Tags: android, connection

Well I am using this code:

```
public boolean isOnline() {
     ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
     return cm.getActiveNetworkInfo().isConnectedOrConnecting();

    }
```

but it always return true. Can anyone tell me why? Moreover, this function check either if the device is connected using wifi or 3g, or only checks one of them?

Answer (score 1):

Try this method, works for me

```
private boolean isNetworkAvailable() {
    ConnectivityManager connectivityManager 
          = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo activeNetworkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    if (activeNetworkInfo != null)
        return activeNetworkInfo.isConnected();
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Why not add `if (activeNetworkInfo != null) return activeNetworkInfo.isConnected()`?

Answer (score 0):

Use this code and check your permissions. Sometime that might cause the problem as well. Sorry for formatting.

```
 public final boolean isInternetOn() {
ConnectivityManager connec =  (ConnectivityManager)getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
// ARE WE CONNECTED TO THE NET
if ( connec.getNetworkInfo(0).getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED ||
connec.getNetworkInfo(0).getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTING ||
connec.getNetworkInfo(1).getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTING ||
connec.getNetworkInfo(1).getState() == NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED ) {
// MESSAGE TO SCREEN FOR TESTING (IF REQ)
//Toast.makeText(this, connectionType + ” connected”, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
return true;
} else if ( connec.getNetworkInfo(0).getState() == NetworkInfo.State.DISCONNECTED ||  connec.getNetworkInfo(1).getState() == NetworkInfo.State.DISCONNECTED  ) {
//System.out.println(“Not Connected”);
return false;
}
return false;
}
```

The following code demonstrates how to call the above method;

```
 if(isInternetOn()) {
// INTERNET IS AVAILABLE, DO STUFF..
return true;
}else{
// NO INTERNET AVAILABLE, DO STUFF..
return false;
}
```

Comment: It doesn't seem to work. I have added in the manifest the line: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" but still not. It always returns true, even with the answer above. Maybe its a silly question but: How do I turn the internet off in the emulator, just disconect my pc from the internet, right?

Comment: Yes, just disconnect your pc from the internet..As the long as the computer has internet access, the emulator will probably have internet access also..From past experiences this has been the case

Answer (score 0):

I use this, it allows me to check for a specific connection (3g or wifi) (found somewhere on SO but lost the reference, sorry)

```
public boolean isConnected() {
    boolean connectedWifi = false;
    boolean connectedMobile = false;

    ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo[] networks = cm.getAllNetworkInfo();
    for (NetworkInfo ni : networks) {
        if ("WIFI".equalsIgnoreCase(ni.getTypeName()))
            if (ni.isConnected())
                connectedWifi = true;
        if ("MOBILE".equalsIgnoreCase(ni.getTypeName()))
            if (ni.isConnected())
                connectedMobile = true;
    }
    return connectedWifi || connectedMobile;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well if you want to know whether your android device is connected to any network then you can follow the approach what other people are telling you.

But if you want to know that internet is working or not then there is no API in android to check it. The only way to know if internet is working or not is due to check my making http request to any web URL.

Comment: I am retrieving data from a DB in my app. So I want, if there is no Internet instead of trying to receive the data, set the view in a error.xml which will display a message.

Comment: Then u can follow this approach, make a http request to any two URLs may be google.com and facebook.com and if both these http reqests don't return 200 response,  then you should know that net is not working

Answer (score -1):

Following code works for me

```
public static boolean haveNetworkConnection(Activity activity) {
        int airplane_mode_on = Settings.System.getInt(activity
                .getApplicationContext().getContentResolver(),
                Settings.System.AIRPLANE_MODE_ON, 0);
        if (airplane_mode_on == 1) {
            return false;
        } else {
            return checkInternetConnection(activity);
        }
    }

    private static boolean checkInternetConnection(Context context) {
        ConnectivityManager conMgr = (ConnectivityManager) context
                .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        if (conMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo() != null
                && conMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo().isAvailable()
                && conMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo().isConnected()) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: You can have WiFi enabled when you have turned on Airplane mode.